# Login into a webgape using Headless Chrome and Python: How to do that?

Tags: python, google-chrome, beautifulsoup, headless

How can I login into a webpage(fill and submit the login/pass form tag) using Headless Chrome. I made a web crawler with Python 3, BeautifulSoup and Headless Chrome but now I need to login first and I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

For filling form and other after loading action, I have used Selenium.
You can check [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms) for selenium documentation.
It is like beautifuilsoup and very easy to use.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import (
        presence_of_element_located)
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
url = 'https://example.com'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'path\chromedriver.exe')
```